# when using ftplib in python

Tags: python, ftplib

Here is the relevant code that's causing the Error.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP('server')
ftp.login(r'user', r'pass')

#change directories to the "incoming" folder
ftp.cwd('incoming')

fileObj = open(fromDirectory + os.sep + f, 'rb')

#push the file
try:
    msg = ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % f, fileObj)
except Exception as inst:
    msg = inst
finally:
    fileObj.close()
    if '226' not in msg:
    #handle error case
```

I've never seen this error before and any information about why I might be getting it would be useful and appreciated.

complete error message:
[Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

It should be noted that when I manually (i.e. open a dos-prompt and push the files using ftp commands) push the file from the same machine that the script is on, I have no problems.

Comment: 10060 looks like a timeout error.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=error+10060

Comment: nothing particularly helpful in the google search w/r/t how to handle in python.

Comment: @Ignacio, I appreciate the help. But you don't have to put your assistance in the form of a condescending question. You could have simply said: "you can't handle a server error in the client".

Comment: The server isn't responding. I'm... not really sure why you would think you can handle that...

Comment: I didn't know it was a server-side error. Thank you for clarifying for me.

Comment: A timeout could be related to active/passive FTP, as the answer to this question suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451817/python-ftplib-timing-out

Comment: turned out to be a mandatory ACTV mode setting on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, changing to ACTV mode, as @Anders Lindahl suggested, got everything back into working order.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should increase the "**timeout**" option, and let the server more time to response.